# How to fix MT3001 error when deploying a Xamarin.Forms iOS app with AspNet Zero to an iPhone device?

Tags: xamarin.forms, aspnetzero

I have a Xamarin.forms IOS application and it's using AspNet Zero. The application works well on the emulator for both debug and release but when I try and deploy it to a real (IPhone) device in release mode and debug mode, I get the error below

/Users/jerryd/Documents/GitHub/Boostr/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Mobile.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/jerryd/Documents/GitHub/Boostr/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/3-Build/Abp.dll' (MT3001) (MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Mobile.iOS)

Tried copying a new Abp.dll file to the location. Also tried to change the Link behaviour to Linking All, but AspNet Zero does not support linking and this creates a new error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.